# Office solutions add-in for word. Generic wpf/win32

Tags: wpf, winforms, ms-word, ms-office

I want my program to show two documents: one is the original, and the other a processed document of the original. I'm trying to deliver a side-by-side view of them in word, currently using office solutions. Since you cannot split vertically [1], I thought about using the view side-by-side feature which word uses, which simply takes two windows and modifies their shape so that they can both be shown on the screen [2].

I have managed to create a new processed document, however I'm not sure about how to go about moving the windows so that they can be placed side by side. I feel like I need to call something from WinApi, but I don't know how to do this or where to look. Thanks in advance!

TL;DR - I need a way to arrange two windows like in [2].

Thanks in advance!

[1] http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/view-two-parts-of-a-document-simultaneously-HP005189321.aspx - last paragraph

[2] http://img.bhs4.com/a5/4/a546784b3a5df0cf6a122f11812a905aa2a9affb_large.jpg

Comment: Please clarify if you want the two panels to include instances of Word?  Or simply the documents?  Your image [2] looks like you want side by side instances of Word

Comment: Either, documents are fine.